# Angular 6: getting error with starting my app with npm start

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, node-modules, package.json

I've been working on a angular 6 project for a long time and when I had `node_modules` folder inside my project folder it was working just fine.
I want to be able to run my project without the `node_modules` inside my project so I moved the `node_modules` folder to a parent folder and changed in `angular.json` the path to start with `../node_modules`.
I thought it'll work, but after I wrote npm start I got this error:

```html
pm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! lg-academy@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --configuration=production --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --verbose --disable-host-check`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lg-academy@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ofir/.npm/_logs/2018-11-15T1
```

Thanks beforehand for all the helpers

Comment: have you ran `npm i` before?

Comment: You cannot simply move `node_modules` it has to be where `package.json` is - why do you feel the need to move it?

Comment: yes, I wrote that when the node_modules were inside my project folder everthing worked. I've been working with the node_modules inside my project folder for 2 months and everything was fine. I want to deploy this project without being dependent on the node_modules folder inside. Creating a image is taking too much time and I think it's not suppose to be like that so I want to see if in development I can make it work without it

Comment: Normally you don't relocate the node_modules folder. It is heavy, yes, but if you want to deploy the project to production server, you just don't upload the node_modules folder with it. You just need the package.json file there and execute "npm install" at the production server and it's done.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that but It is EXACTLY supposed to be like that. A project with a package.json has to rely on a node_modules folder, where to store all the project dependencies. You should consider running some script to automatically `npm install` while deploying.

Comment: The production mode of an Angular app is generally the static files created by the build command, so you don't need any of this in production anyway.

Answer (score 0):

after the answers I got here and on google and asked some of my friends, I just deployed everything and return the node_modules to my project folder. it takes so much time to deploy it, but there isn't any other way.

Thank you for your comments and help!